# Does 京都 use じゃ、や、or だ？

Tags: words, dialects

Also, is ね used at all in 関西？ I know な is at least more common, even among female speakers. And has どす fallen out of use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience with speakers in Kyoto is that they use や most if they're going to use dialectal patterns. 関西 men also, surprisingly to me, use わ fairly regularly.

I've never heard どす, but it's possible I just never caught it.